# Add http.port to application.conf

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using play and I want to specifiy the port in application.conf because I'm going to deploy it to cloud.

I've been reading post regarding this question but all answers are about putting it when typing play start. Is there really a way to add it in application.conf?

thanks!

Comment: Which cloud you want to deploy to?

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is no way to do that.

That is how play's Netty Server initialised:

```
val server = new NettyServer(
    new StaticApplication(applicationPath),
    Option(System.getProperty("http.port")).map(Integer.parseInt(_)).getOrElse(9000),
    Option(System.getProperty("https.port")).map(Integer.parseInt(_)),
    Option(System.getProperty("http.address")).getOrElse("0.0.0.0")
  )
```

So it using system property or "9000" if the first one was not set.

In our production env we just pass it within args "`-Dhttp.port=<port>`".

What are the complexities with your cloud?

Answer (score -4):

Maybe I am missing something but have you tried to specify **http.port=80** in your application.conf?

Comment: This doesn't work. Please try something before you post it as an answer